# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver

Tags: maven, ubuntu, hadoop, classnotfoundexception, mahout

I am trying to run this statement:
CODE:

```
/usr/local/lib/mahout/bin$ mahout seqwiki -i /user/wiki/enwiki-articles.xml -o /user/wiki/kmeansseqfiles
```

ERROR:

```
MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, so we don't add HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath.
MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, running locally
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver
```

I followed the top voted instructions from this [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973324/running-mahout-localy-getting-classnotfoundexception-for-mahoutdriver)

However I still get the same error.

Where all my pom.xml files are

```
./mahout/hdfs/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/integration/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/math-scala/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/buildtools/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/examples/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/math/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/distribution/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/spark/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/mrlegacy/pom.xml
./mahout/trunk/spark-shell/pom.xml
./mahout/integration/pom.xml
./mahout/math-scala/pom.xml
./mahout/buildtools/pom.xml
./mahout/examples/pom.xml
./mahout/flink/pom.xml
./mahout/math/pom.xml
./mahout/distribution/pom.xml
./mahout/mr/pom.xml
./mahout/pom.xml
./mahout/spark/pom.xml
./mahout/spark-shell/pom.xml
./mahout/h2o/pom.xml
```

when I do a clean install

```
hadoop@ip-:/usr/local/lib/mahout$ mvn -DskipTests -X clean install
```

Error:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/lib/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.7.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-91-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

[INFO] Mahout Build Tools ................................. FAILURE [  1.140 s]
[INFO] Apache Mahout ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Math ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout HDFS ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Map-Reduce .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Integration ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Math Scala bindings ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Spark bindings .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Flink bindings .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Spark bindings shell ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Release Package ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout H2O backend ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

ls -l

```
total 160
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 buildtools
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17916 Oct 24 02:51 CHANGELOG
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 distribution
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2313 Oct 24 02:51 doap_Mahout.rdf
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 examples
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 integration
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 39588 Oct 24 02:51 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 math
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 math-scala
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 mrlegacy
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1888 Oct 24 02:51 NOTICE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43921 Oct 24 02:51 pom.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   479 Oct 24 02:51 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 spark
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 spark-shell
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Oct 24 02:51 src
```